# Create a Mutex with Priority Inheritance in C#

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, mutex

I have a static list of objects.
During the program, many thread are created.
Immediately after each thread is created, it creates a new object, and add it to the static list.
There is another thread in the program, that responsible to iterating over the static list.

Suppose that a thread with a low priority 'A' is access to the list, and another thread with a higher priority 'C' asks also access to it, May (in a rare case indeed),that thread with medium priority 'B' that exists in the system too, will get the CPU time of 'A'.
So, 'C' will wait for 'B', contrary to common sense.

How do I can get a lock to the List, without getting involved with this Priority inversion problem?

The function 'Lock()' can help?

Thank you!

Comment: No, `lock` won't help. Nor will the `Mutex` class. Those are FIFO. As I recall, all of the Windows synchronization objects are FIFO. What problem are you really trying to solve? It's ... unusual for synchronization objects to cause a serious priority inversion problem. If they do, then I would suspect the application design is not as it should be.

Comment: I want to add a list that will be accessible to many processes..

Comment: What does "accessible" mean here? Are high priority threads and low priority threads both adding and removing items? Primarily reading, but sometimes writing? Iterating over the list and performing complex operations? Without knowing more about how the list is being accessed, it's impossible to make any recommendation or even determine if priority inversion is a potential problem.

Comment: Many threads are registered to the List, and there is another thread that responsible to iterating over the list and performing complex operations.

Comment: What does "registered to the List" mean? Do they add things to it? Remove things from it? Just query it? You need to edit your question and provide many more details about how you're using this data structure, and explain why you think there might be a priority inversion problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is, at worst, a *short term* priority inversion problem. Unless, of course, the low priority thread A holds the lock for a very long time. Thread C can't make progress because it's waiting on the lock. As Hans Passant said in his answer, the thread scheduler detects this problem and boosts the priority of the lower-priority thread so that it can release the lock. The first MSDN link he posted explains it quite well.

If your low priority thread A holds the lock for a very long time (i.e. it's doing complex calculations on the list) and that's causing problems in your application, then you can do one of the following:

- Increase the priority of thread A
- Have thread A lock the list, get an item, unlock the list, and then process the item
- Lock the list, make a copy, unlock the list, and process the copy.
- some variation on or combination of the above

In any case, the problem isn't the lock. The problem is coding the program so that a high-priorty thread can be left waiting for a long time on a data structure that a lower priority thread needs exclusive access to.

Answer (score 2):

Priority inversion is a very generic problem on an operating system that uses thread priority to pick the next thread to schedule.  Like Windows.  The operating system thread scheduler has specific countermeasures against it, artificially bumping the thread priority when it detects an inversion problem so the low-priority thread is allowed to run and given an opportunity to release the lock.  The MSDN page that describes the feature [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684831%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  And old KB article with more details [is here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/96418).

Do not help.

Comment: So .. If I understand it.. If I will block a resource access by the 'Lock' function, Windows will ensure that there will not be a problem?

Comment: There's very little evidence that you are actually talking about a priority inversion problem in that comment.  Using SyncLock in your code is fraught with many problems, deadlock and starvation being most common, but none that have anything to do with a priority inversion problem.  Do read a book about it to stay out of trouble.